# how to check the record existence based on id and status in odoo

Tags: odoo

How i can create a new examination record against a patient with 'open' status after checking if previous record is not in 'open' state. If exist then show error otherwise new record created.

Below code does not properly checking record existence in 'if record.id:', so directly raise error message.

here is my code :

```py
@api.multi
@api.constrains('status', 'patient_id')
def _checkstatus(self):
    res = []

    for record in self:
        if record.id:
            if record.status == 'open':
                raise ValidationError(_('You can not create new visit until patient checked out !' ))  
            else:
                res = self.status    
        else:
                res = self.status  

    return res
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to first fetch all record with patient and status == open.
like that,

```
self.env['your.model.name'].search([('patient_id', '=', patient_id), ('status', '=', 'open')])
```

if there is record found then raise a error.
Here a write a code for ex. change a name as per you code.

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('status', 'patient_id')
def _checkstatus(self):
    res = []

    modelObj = self.env['your.model.name']
    for record in self:
        rec = modelObj.search([('patient_id', '=', record.patient_id), ('status', '=', 'open')])
        if rec:
            raise ValidationError(_('You can not create new visit until patient checked out !' ))  
        else:
            // write a login if there is not found any open record with patient

    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo, when evaluating a constrain, records has already been created / updated.

Which mean that, in your case, you need to **exclude** the current recordset from your lookup data (you want to know if other patients entries are in 'open' state).

Raising an error here will cause Odoo to [rollback](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-rollback.html) its transactions data, and prevent any **persistent** modification.

```py
@api.multi
@api.constrains('status', 'patient_id')
def _checkstatus(self):
    # retrieve patients in the current records
    patients_tocheck = self.mapped('patient_id')
    duplicates == self.search([('patient_id', 'in', patients_tocheck.ids), ('id', 'not in', self.ids), ('status', '=', 'open')])
    if duplicates:
        raise ValidationError(_('You can not create new visit until patient checked out !' ))  
    # moreover, you don't need to return any value, Odoo only see if you raise any error, or not
```

Comment: you're welcome ^^ could you just set your question as Answered please ?
Thanks you ^^